# Can't send mails wordpress using SMTP authenticate

Tags: plugins

I use wordpress WP-Mail-SMTP plugin to send mails with proper authentication. I have a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS, Nginx, Wordpress 3.9. When I try to send test mails, I can see following main debug message and it's not sending any mail.

> SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

This is the full debug [IN HERE](http://pastebin.com/YeVsn71P).

Could someone please tell me how do I fix this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to an outdated WordPress version.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with WordPress 3.9 that has caused many if not all email and newsletter based plugins to stop working. I am a Web Developer and am working with 7 different hosts at the moment to resolve issues with 30+ client sites all which were upgraded to 3.9 and web forms and newsletter plugins no longer work. The sites that were not updated to 3.9 still function.

Comment: Thanks Roger, I have the latest wordperss version (3.9). I experience this issue since 1 month ago. I don't think this is a wordperss issue. Probably it's a some sort of dependencies issue. How do i identify it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - updated wp to 3.9 and smtp error log was 'can't connect'

As a solution I replaced the class-phpmailer.php and class-smtp.php files in the wp-includes folder with the previous version. Now everything works back again..

I got the answer from this page http://bobylive.com/static/1935913 (translated with chrome)
there is a zip file containing the mentioned files.

Hope this will work for everyone - i was going crazy about this..